# Why does adding an if statement give me a TypeError: "float" not iterable?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am creating a program that searches for a cell in the rightmost column containing a non-zero float.

Here is the section which calls on the helper function and applies it to each row:

```
for index, row in supplier.iterrows():
        if row[2] not in storage["Product"] and not pd.isnull(row[2]):
            if find_most_recent(j, supplier) != 0:
                storage["Product"].append(row[2])
                storage["Most Recent Price"].append(find_most_recent(j,
                                                                supplier))
        j += 1
```

Here is the helper function which does what I explained above :

```
def find_most_recent(row_num: int, df) -> float:
k = -1
checker = False
while not checker and k > -len(df.columns):
    if "final cost" in df.columns[k]:
        if not pd.isnull(df.iloc[row_num, k]): #and df.iloc[row_num, k] > 0:
            checker = True
            return df.loc[row_num, df.columns[k]]
    k -= 1
```

For some reason, adding the commented out `df.iloc[row_num, k] > 0` portion gives me a

> TypeError: "float" not iterable.

It works fine without errors (just not the way I want it to) without this part.

I know this is a very commonly asked question but I have tried and tried and can't seem to figure out what is wrong since I am clearly not trying to iterate over a float?

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Can you add the full structure of your `df` / `supplier`? This looks more likely that you think df.iloc is an array however it is actually just a float.

Comment: Supplier is a List and the df is a dict of form {"Product": [a,b,c...], "Price": [a,b,c...]} With the same number of entries in each key. I'm not sure if that's what you were asking for so please let me know.

Comment: well, you're passing supplier (a list) as a second argument to `find_most_recent` and then use `iloc` on it. I wonder why it doesn't throw in the first part of the if

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: There can be a NaN/None value among the rows it is trying to scan. try `df[column].isnan().sum()` and see for yourself if there's any

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the data so that we can reproduce this? Or maybe a screenshot of the full error message

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete. What is the initial value of *j*? Another remark: Why do you use negative value of *k* in *iloc* (and also as the index in *columns*)?